# Custom eloquent's table()->insert() function

Tags: php, eloquent

I'm trying to modify eloquent's basic functionnality of `Manager::table('table')->insert($array)` (and `Manager::table('table')->update($array)`) but I'm not sure how.

I've got a class that extends of the manager :

```
class Database extends \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager
```

Inside that class I created a function that extends of `table()` but I'm not sure how to make it extend of it's `insert` and `update` because the `table()` function returns an [`\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html) and that builder in question is totally separate of the Manager.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

The end goal is having my own modified version of the `insert` so when I do this `Manager::table('table')->insert($array)`, the insert would do something like the following and not the original insert :

```
public function insert(array $values)
{
    if (empty($values)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (! is_array(reset($values))) {
        $values = [$values];
    } else {
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            ksort($value);

            ($value == NULL) ? $values[$key] = '' : $values[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $this->connection->insert(
        $this->grammar->compileInsert($this, $values),
        $this->cleanBindings(Arr::flatten($values, 1))
    );
}
```

(Note that the code above is the copy/paste version of the actual function modified by my needs, so it's normal stuff like `Arr::flatten` would cause problems if I just copy/paste the function somewhere. So I'm trying to find an official way to EXTEND that said function so I wouldn't have to worry about such problems)

Comment: what is the purpose of adding such a function to eloquent lib ?

Comment: @Sameera the purpose is to have full control over what's being sent to the database. For example, in this case, it's to see if the values added are equal to NULL, if they are then replace them with empty strings. This is just an example to show that I need to have full control over the data that is being sent to the database. Also I'm not looking to *add* a function, I'm looking to extend the existing one and modify it.

Comment: @Equgonkya I think instead of extending manager, you can extend Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder and override insert function as your need.